# Using cracked software and tools

Tags: tools, software

I am seeing people complaining about expensive tools such as Dreamweaver or Photoshop. I am just wondering about that, because everyone knows that they can get this software running for free (if it is done illegally). Why don't they just use a cracked version? Is it so likely to get caught?

I feel that nowadays a lot of people are using cracked software but whenever the topic is mentioned, they ALL say PSSST!!! or start criticizing it, even though they are doing it themselves...

Answer (score 1):

Using cracked software is a big risk, learning a freeware alternative pays of more in the long run, take for example GIMP and Adobe Photoshop, at first doing things in GIMP wasn't so smooth, but now you can do a really great job with it.

Also I think free software changes less radically overtime not necessitating to ramp-up on learning where is stuff and how to do stuff that was in plain sight before.